# EF6 GroupJoin() repeats a subquery several times

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

Not a serious problem, but still quite unpleasant... Okay, so the environment is: SQL Server 2012, VS 2012, .NET 4.5 WinForms, EF 6.1.3

I am trying to retrieve data from table, along with its localisation on the current language (selected by user). If I would write the query myself, it would look like this:

```
declare @Id int = 1, @CultureCode varchar(50) = 'en';

select ci.Id, ci.Name, ci.ItemPosition,
    isnull(vls.TextData, ci.Description) as [Description]
from dbo.SomeTable ci
    left join dbo.ViewLocalisedStrings vls on vls.CultureCode = @CultureCode
        and vls.ObjectType = 'SOMETYPE' and vls.RowId = ci.Id
where ci.ClassifierId = @Id;
```

Here, I resort to the item description only if its localisation is absent. In the application, the following construct has been concocted (Ctx is an Entity Framework context reference):

```
Ctx.SomeTable.Where(Function(c) c.ClassifierId = ClId).GroupJoin( _
    Ctx.ViewLocalisedStrings.Where(Function(c) c.CultureCode = G_DBCulture And c.ObjectType = "SOMETYPE"), _
    Function(o) o.Id,
    Function(vls) vls.RowId,
    Function(o, vls) New With { _
        .Id = o.Id, _
        .Name = o.Name, _
        .ItemPosition = o.ItemPosition, _
        .Description = CStr(If(vls.FirstOrDefault().TextData, o.Description))
    } _
)
```

The resulting query generated by EF, however, is far from perfect:

```
declare @p__linq__0 int = 1, @p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000) = 'en';

SELECT 
    [Project6].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project6].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project6].[ItemPosition] AS [ItemPosition], 
    CASE WHEN ([Project6].[C1] IS NULL) THEN [Project6].[Description] ELSE [Project6].[C2] END AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project4].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project4].[ItemPosition] AS [ItemPosition], 
        [Project4].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Project4].[Description] AS [Description], 
        [Project4].[C1] AS [C1], 
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent3].[TextData] AS [TextData]
            FROM [dbo].[ViewLocalisedStrings] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE ([Extent3].[CultureCode] = @p__linq__1) AND ('SOMETYPE' = [Extent3].[ObjectType]) AND ([Project4].[Id] = [Extent3].[RowId])) AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project3].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project3].[ItemPosition] AS [ItemPosition], 
            [Project3].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Project3].[Description] AS [Description], 
            [Project3].[C1] AS [C1]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Project1].[ItemPosition] AS [ItemPosition], 
                [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
                [Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
                (SELECT TOP (1) 
                    [Extent2].[TextData] AS [TextData]
                    FROM [dbo].[ViewLocalisedStrings] AS [Extent2]
                    WHERE ([Extent2].[CultureCode] = @p__linq__1) AND ('SOMETYPE' = [Extent2].[ObjectType]) AND ([Project1].[Id] = [Extent2].[RowId])) AS [C1]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    @p__linq__1 AS [p__linq__1], 
                    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                    [Extent1].[ItemPosition] AS [ItemPosition], 
                    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
                    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
                    FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent1]
                    WHERE [Extent1].[ClassifierId] = @p__linq__0
                )  AS [Project1]
            )  AS [Project3]
        )  AS [Project4]
    )  AS [Project6];
```

Localised text is retrieved twice (or more - depends on which function is used instead of `If()`), and then each version is used in the final `CASE` statement in a manner I would like to unsee, really.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this with a better query being generated? Any suggestion is welcome, short of redesigning the database (probably).

P.S. Yes, it is possible to return both fields separately and then decide which will go on the client side, but this approach stops working when the query is used as a datasource.

Comment: Report this to the team on Github or Codeplex. Provide the with a small repro. The team is responsive. I see LINQ translation fixes weekly in the commit logs.